# Mysql to JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a music sharing script and i am trying to create JSON from my mysql database, I'm trying to create a specific structure and can't seem to figure it out

heres my code

```
<?php
    //Create Database connection
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","-Username-","-Password-");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select the Database
    mysql_select_db("-Database-",$db);


{

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY username ASC"); 
    $json_response = array(); //Create an array
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $row_array = array();
        $row_array['idu'] = $row['idu'];
        $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];
        $row_array['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $row_array['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
        $row_array['country'] = $row['country'];
        $row_array['image'] = $row['image'];
        $row_array['cover'] = $row['cover'];
        $row_array['description'] = $row['description'];
        $row_array['playlists'] = array();  
        $row_array['tracks'] = array();  
        $plid = $row['idu'];

        $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlists where playlists.by=$plid");
        while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
        {
            $row_array['playlists'][] = array(
                'id' => $opt_fet['id'],
                'name' => $opt_fet['name'],
                'by' => $opt_fet['by'],
            );


        }
        array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array


        //tracks


        $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks where tracks.uid=$plid");
        while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
        {
            $row_array['tracks'][] = array(
                'id' => $opt_fet['id'],
                'title' => $opt_fet['title'],
                'name' => $opt_fet['name'],
                'art' => $opt_fet['art'],
                'likes' => $opt_fet['likes'],
                'downloads' => $opt_fet['downloads'],
                'plays' => $opt_fet['views'],
                'uid' => $opt_fet['uid'],



            );


        }
        array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array

    }
    echo json_encode($json_response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
?>
```

users Table:

```
id  username   last_name  first_name  country etc...
1   username1  Mynce      George      USA     etc...
2   username2  Jenkins    Fred        USA     etc...
3   username3  Walberg    Mark        USA     etc...
4   username4  Smith      Will        USA     etc...
```

playlists Table:

```
id   by  name
1    4   My playlists
2    3   Popular Songs
```

playlistentries Table:

```
id  playlists   track
12  1           13
13  1           23
14  1           3
15  1           17
16  1           9
12  2           14
13  2           24
14  2           4
15  2           18
16  2           10
```

tracks Table:

```
id  title      name      art      likes  downloads  views
1   song_title song1.mp3 art1.png 13     8          55
2   song_title song2.mp3 art2.png 12     10         31
3   song_title song3.mp3 art3.png 7      32         50
4   song_title song4.mp3 art4.png 22     11         1
5   song_title song5.mp3 art5.png 1      28         2
```

With my current code i am getting this JSON result:

```
{
    "idu": "2",
    "username": "chicagochurch",
    "first_name": "Chicago Christian Center",
    "last_name": "",
    "country": "United States",
    "image": "839674815_146358938_1746691162.png",
    "cover": "173157219_1187606488_302826016.jpg",
    "description": "This is the official Chicago Church Music page.",
    "playlists": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "We Give You Praise",
            "by": "2"
        }
    ],
    "tracks": [
        {
            "id": "29",
            "title": "01 We Give You Praise",
            "name": "1667450919_35711384_1898671201.mp3",
            "art": "97020012_1272964020_1490042512.png",
            "likes": "1",
            "downloads": "1",
            "plays": "4",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "30",
            "title": "02 Luvudees",
            "name": "1361859314_884859216_209326964.mp3",
            "art": "1591964284_1156840179_1721104535.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "1",
            "plays": "3",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "31",
            "title": "03 Mugo Del",
            "name": "1366849477_130736941_1367659635.mp3",
            "art": "1181156184_556035815_1698596436.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "1",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "title": "04 San Amensa",
            "name": "40925819_971317614_1732715256.mp3",
            "art": "837149755_251638008_1945445596.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "0",
            "plays": "1",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "33",
            "title": "05 One True God",
            "name": "1201163785_1107025307_1077346045.mp3",
            "art": "713651840_1636034922_1247445482.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "0",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "34",
            "title": "06 Mugo Anav",
            "name": "173569477_686122962_117960391.mp3",
            "art": "1432749408_578109445_1094716795.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "0",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "35",
            "title": "07 Hallelujah",
            "name": "133051077_70993845_552471086.mp3",
            "art": "2040610215_1811023913_383444282.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "0",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "36",
            "title": "08 Sheppard",
            "name": "984429058_1532916377_1375134853.mp3",
            "art": "1153269141_143559426_997684622.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "0",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "37",
            "title": "09 I Love you Lord",
            "name": "794115968_1411878888_673035094.mp3",
            "art": "1692460167_1433248811_682631716.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "0",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "38",
            "title": "10 Jesus In The Center",
            "name": "202390322_461558278_1271927584.mp3",
            "art": "1048499380_362527600_4599069.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "1",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "39",
            "title": "11 Mugo Luvudeemos",
            "name": "274506373_302381815_356651583.mp3",
            "art": "1229728795_739090349_686501748.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "1",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "40",
            "title": "12 Onday Chedo Kud",
            "name": "378498031_1470949688_1199351944.mp3",
            "art": "308978665_1074723934_419931699.png",
            "likes": "0",
            "downloads": "0",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "41",
            "title": "13 The Word",
            "name": "956461611_287666310_43661088.mp3",
            "art": "1584112229_240532531_977129308.png",
            "likes": "1",
            "downloads": "4",
            "plays": "0",
            "uid": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

what i actually want to get this kind of structure:

```
{
    "idu": "2",
    "username": "chicagochurch",
    "first_name": "Chicago Christian Center",
    "last_name": "",
    "country": "United States",
    "image": "839674815_146358938_1746691162.png",
    "cover": "173157219_1187606488_302826016.jpg",
    "description": "This is the official Chicago Church Music page.",
    "playlists": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "We Give You Praise",
            "by": "2",
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "id": "29",
                    "title": "01 We Give You Praise",
                    "name": "1667450919_35711384_1898671201.mp3",
                    "art": "97020012_1272964020_1490042512.png",
                    "likes": "1",
                    "downloads": "1",
                    "plays": "4",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "30",
                    "title": "02 Luvudees",
                    "name": "1361859314_884859216_209326964.mp3",
                    "art": "1591964284_1156840179_1721104535.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "1",
                    "plays": "3",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "31",
                    "title": "03 Mugo Del",
                    "name": "1366849477_130736941_1367659635.mp3",
                    "art": "1181156184_556035815_1698596436.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "1",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "32",
                    "title": "04 San Amensa",
                    "name": "40925819_971317614_1732715256.mp3",
                    "art": "837149755_251638008_1945445596.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "0",
                    "plays": "1",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "33",
                    "title": "05 One True God",
                    "name": "1201163785_1107025307_1077346045.mp3",
                    "art": "713651840_1636034922_1247445482.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "0",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "34",
                    "title": "06 Mugo Anav",
                    "name": "173569477_686122962_117960391.mp3",
                    "art": "1432749408_578109445_1094716795.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "0",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "35",
                    "title": "07 Hallelujah",
                    "name": "133051077_70993845_552471086.mp3",
                    "art": "2040610215_1811023913_383444282.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "0",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "36",
                    "title": "08 Sheppard",
                    "name": "984429058_1532916377_1375134853.mp3",
                    "art": "1153269141_143559426_997684622.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "0",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37",
                    "title": "09 I Love you Lord",
                    "name": "794115968_1411878888_673035094.mp3",
                    "art": "1692460167_1433248811_682631716.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "0",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "38",
                    "title": "10 Jesus In The Center",
                    "name": "202390322_461558278_1271927584.mp3",
                    "art": "1048499380_362527600_4599069.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "1",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "39",
                    "title": "11 Mugo Luvudeemos",
                    "name": "274506373_302381815_356651583.mp3",
                    "art": "1229728795_739090349_686501748.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "1",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "40",
                    "title": "12 Onday Chedo Kud",
                    "name": "378498031_1470949688_1199351944.mp3",
                    "art": "308978665_1074723934_419931699.png",
                    "likes": "0",
                    "downloads": "0",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "41",
                    "title": "13 The Word",
                    "name": "956461611_287666310_43661088.mp3",
                    "art": "1584112229_240532531_977129308.png",
                    "likes": "1",
                    "downloads": "4",
                    "plays": "0",
                    "uid": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see in the above structure, the playlists is listing the tracks associated with it in its own nested array, I'm sure the playlistentries table will need to be used for this but I dont know how to implement it, Sorry for all the code... but thanks for your help!

Comment: @CharlotteDunois i tried moving the tracks array into the "()" of the playlists array but i was getting errors, and then i figured out that i need to use playlistentries somehow to populate the array for each playlists nested tracks - this is past my skill level and was hoping someone can show me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

to get tracks of a playlist you should add a new column in your tracks table called in playlist, so you can run a mysql query and get tracks WHERE inplaylist = x

this is my solution (tested on localhost):

```
<?php
//Create Database connection
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("test",$db);




$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY username ASC"); 
$json_response = array(); //Create an array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $row_array = array();
    $row_array['idu'] = $row['idu'];
    $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];
    $row_array['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
    $row_array['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
    $row_array['country'] = $row['country'];
    $row_array['image'] = $row['image'];
    $row_array['cover'] = $row['cover'];
    $row_array['description'] = $row['description'];
    $row_array['playlists'] = array();  
    $plid = $row['idu'];

    $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlists where playlists.by=$plid");
    $playlist = 1;
    while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
    {

        $row_array['playlists'][$playlist]['id'] = $opt_fet['id'];
        $row_array['playlists'][$playlist]['name'] = $opt_fet['name'];
        $row_array['playlists'][$playlist]['by'] = $opt_fet['by'];

        $tracks_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks where tracks.uid=$plid AND tracks.inplaylist = {$opt_fet['id']}");
        while ($tcks_fet = mysql_fetch_array($tracks_qry))
        {
            $row_array['playlists'][$playlist]['tracks'][] = array(
                'id' => $tcks_fet['id'],
                'title' => $tcks_fet['title'],
                'name' => $tcks_fet['name'],
                'art' => $tcks_fet['art'],
                'likes' => $tcks_fet['likes'],
                'downloads' => $tcks_fet['downloads'],
                'plays' => $tcks_fet['views'],
                'uid' => $tcks_fet['uid'],
            );
        }
        $playlist++;
    }

    //tracks




    array_push($json_response, $row_array);

}
print "<pre>";
echo json_encode($json_response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

my output:

```
[
    {
        "idu": "2",
        "username": "chicagochurch",
        "first_name": "Chicago Christian Center",
        "last_name": "",
        "country": "United States",
        "image": "8396748146691162.png",
        "cover": "1731572302826016.jpg",
        "description": "Music page.",
        "playlists": {
            "1": {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "We Give You Praise",
                "by": "2",
                "tracks": [
                    {
                        "id": "29",
                        "title": "01 We Give You Praise",
                        "name": "1667450919_35711384_1898671201.mp3",
                        "art": "97020012_1272964020_1490042512.png",
                        "likes": "1",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "4",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "30",
                        "title": "02 Luvudees",
                        "name": "1361859314_884859216_209326964.mp3",
                        "art": "1591964284_1156840179_1721104535.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "3",
                        "uid": "2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "2": {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "We Give You Praise 2",
                "by": "2"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the tracks that are within a playlists nested under the playlists like this user1>playlists1>track1,track2,track3 and  user1>playlist2>track1,track2,track3 get it?

Comment: i've edit the solution, i believe this is what you are looking for

Comment: the data is being generated by a script i purchased from codecanyon table structure is already set the way it is, they way it links up tracks into playlist is in another table called "playlistentries" as you can see above in my original post, i just dont know how to use that table to link it up in this script

Answer (score 1):

try this, code

```
<?php
//Create Database connection
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","-Username-","-Password-");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("-Database-",$db);
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY username ASC"); 
$json_response = array(); //Create an array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $row_array = array();
    $row_array['idu'] = $row['idu'];
    $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];
    $row_array['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
    $row_array['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
    $row_array['country'] = $row['country'];
    $row_array['image'] = $row['image'];
    $row_array['cover'] = $row['cover'];
    $row_array['description'] = $row['description'];
    $row_array['playlists'] = array();  
    //$row_array['tracks'] = array();  
    $plid = $row['idu'];

    $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlists where  playlists.by=$plid");
    while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
    {
        $row_array['playlists'][] = array(
            'id' => $opt_fet['id'],
            'name' => $opt_fet['name'],
            'by' => $opt_fet['by'],
        );


    //}
    //array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array


    //tracks


    $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks where tracks.uid=$plid");
    while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
    {
        $row_array['playlists']['tracks'][] = array(
            'id' => $opt_fet['id'],
            'title' => $opt_fet['title'],
            'name' => $opt_fet['name'],
            'art' => $opt_fet['art'],
            'likes' => $opt_fet['likes'],
            'downloads' => $opt_fet['downloads'],
            'plays' => $opt_fet['views'],
            'uid' => $opt_fet['uid'],



        );


    }
    //array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array
   array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array
 }
}
echo json_encode($json_response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the tracks associated (added to the playlist) nested under the playlists name, so basically the tracks would be a third level nest 1.user>1.2playlist>1.2.1tracks not 1.user>1.2playlist 2tracks

Comment: i tried that code, its almost giving me the same results as my original code